# Stop Powerbi changing date format when converting to text

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to convert a date column to text without changing the date format. I am currently doing this by changing the formatting of that column under the modelling header. The date format is currently DD/MM/YYYY which is what I want. However, when I change the formatting to text it changes the format to MM/DD/YYYY.

My regional settings are set to English(United Kingdom). Any other suggestions as to how I can have exactly the same column but as text rather than date?

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code you are currently using to change the date to text.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `FORMAT` function in a calculated column:

```
FORMAT(Table1[Date], "dd/mm/yyyy")
```